# Django: How to use parent table fields in 'limit_choices_to'?

Tags: python, django

I have two classes *System* and *Station* which inherit from *Base*. The *Base* class has a foreign key to *Group* and *Station* has a foreign key to *System*.

I am trying to place a 'limit_choices_to' constraint on the latter FK, so that the related *System* has to be from the same *Group* as the *Station*.

Here's a snippet of the models.py

```
class Base(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)

class System(Base):
    ...

class Station(Base):
    system_info = models.ForeignKey(System, limit_choices_to={'group': 'self.group'})
```

I've tried a number of ideas, including what is above, but no luck. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: I think you can't refer a field value from the instance in the `limit_choices_to` because this value may not yet be set, and may be changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
system_info = models.ForeignKey(System, limit_choices_to=Q(groups__name= 'group'))
```

I am hoping this will work. Group will be a group name created by you.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to work I'm afraid, throws a syntax error.

Comment: You imported Q?

Comment: Yes, "from django.db.models.query_utils import Q". I'm currently on Django version 1.10.4. It complains about the colon in `group__name: 'group'`. If I replace the colon with an equals sign I get the runtime error:

**invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'group'**

Comment: You need to use colon

Comment: The error is:

system_info = models.ForeignKey(System, limit_choices_to=Q(group__name: 'group'))
                                                                              
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I don't think this will work anyway, as I've just realised you're limiting the choices to the literal string 'group', sorry I thought this was more django magic. The group is basically an arbitrary value that needs to be the same in the System and Station for the relationship to be valid.

Comment: String 'group'  is your group name . You have to replace the value with your own group name. I had updated the syntax , use the updated syntax.